# UITabBarController switch tab is slow at first time

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am working on an ipad project whose UITabBarController (it's also the root) has 5 tabs.

The second tab is a tableview where there are quite rich UI elements.

The problem is that everytime I launch the app and click the second tab, I would be blocked for 0.3 second to show the viewcontroller. However, after the first time enter this tab, it only takes me 0.03 to enter this tab again.

So I thought the `ViewDidLoad` cost too much, because I do a lot `addSubView` or `reloadData` there. So I add

```
[libraryVC viewDidLoad];
[libraryVC viewWillAppear:YES];
[libraryVC viewDidAppear:YES];
```

in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I think if I do this view load stuff before user enter the second tab, then there will be no block.

However after I tested this approach, I found the cost was not be reduced. So I guess the time cost may be used in the view render when first show this viewcontroller. When the viewcontroller's view has been rendered before, then the following show will be fast. But I have no idea to solve this problem.

I think this problem is very common when the viewcontroller's view is really complicated, so does anyone has an idea of the approach to solve this problem? Or does anyone can give a detail description of the reason why the block happens?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps multithreading the time intensive methods/calls is the solution you are looking for. If you search "ios grand central dispatch" on Google, some great resources will be available. Apple's Grand Central Dispatch reference is one of the better pieces of documentation they have.